# Vue-i18n with HTML in named params

Tags: vue.js

Suppose I have this message object:

`{greetings: '{blah} is welcome'}`

How can I inject HTML into that `{blah}`param?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

`{{ $t('greetings', {blah: '<foo>' + some_string + '</foo>'}) }}`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Be cautious of the [previously] accepted answer, as untrusted input will lead to XSS vulnerabilities. The correct way to do this is with [component interpolation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html). It works a little bit like slots.

Here's a practical example that wraps a link around a user's name:

```
const messages = { 
  welcome: 'Welcome, {user}!' 
};
```

```
<i18n
  path="welcome"
  tag="p"
>
  <a place="user" :href="user.link">{{ user.name }}</a>
</i18n>
```

This will result in the following output:

```
<p>Welcome, <a href="/users/bob">Bob Marley</a>!</p>
```

To make it easier to understand, note that:

- The `path` attribute is the message key.
- The `place` attribute the placeholder.
- The `tag` attribute determines what type of element to render.
- For multiple placeholders, simply add more elements with the appropriate `place` attribute.

If you're curious about the `<i18n>` component, you don't have to explicitly enable it — it gets registered when you initialize vue-i18n.

**Update:** as of version 8.14, [`place`](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#places-syntax-usage) is deprecated in favor of the new [slots syntax](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#slots-syntax-usage). Here's an updated example for 8.14 and above:

```
<i18n path="welcome" tag="p">
  <template v-slot:user>
    <a :href="user.link">{{ user.name }}</a>
  </template>
</i18n>
```

Comment: There are cases when this will become pretty not comfortable to use: let's say you have a list with some items, we will call it `productFeatures`. You want to render a list of those items but each of items should have some parts of it **bold** or *italic**, for e.g. This is where using this approach will become a nightmare. It did so for me, I desperately needed `v-html` there

Comment: Let say I have to create computed property for this message string, which approach we have go for?

Answer (score 11):

For Vue 2.0, [things have changed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#HTML-Interpolation-removed):

If your message object is:

```
{greetings: '<foo>{blah}</foo> is welcome'}
```

Then on template side, you should have the following:

```
<p v-html="$t('greetings', {blah: some_string})"></p>
```

Works as well with `<div v-html="..."></div>`, and certainly other tags. See https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/73

Comment: Be careful to use v-html like the official said ' Dynamically localizing arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content.'  https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#list-formatting

Comment: Certainly be careful with v-html and untrusted content, but I doubt much localisation is using user-provided content anyway?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to show me what you're trying to do with that message as far as displaying it in HTML, however at first pass it seems like what you'd want

```
this.msg = '<foo>' + some_string + '</foo>';
```

Then, within your HTML where you want to display this msg, you'd say:

`{{{ msg }}}`

Notice the triple brackets, this means that it is interpreting `msg` as being raw HTML and not an escaped string... use this with caution. If `msg` is purely something set by the front-end then it is fine; just don't let the `some_string` be user inputted data.

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
$t('greetings', {blah: some_string})
```

in their en.json

```
{
greetings: '<foo>{blah}</foo> is welcome'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just use html tag's in json instead of template directly.
here is my combination of dynamic parameters of different layout sentences structure with html tag inside solution

> en.json

```
"Accept_Terms": "Do you accept the <b>{0}</b> and <span class="something">{1}</span> ?",
"Terms":"Terms",
"Conditions":"Conditions"
```

> tr.json

```
"Accept_Terms": "<b>{0}</b> ve <span class="something">{1}</span> kabul ediyor musunuz ??",
"Terms":"Şartları",
"Conditions":"Kullanım koşullarını"
```

> component.vue

```
 <p v-html=" $t('Accept_Terms', [
          $t('Terms'),
          $t('Conditions')
       ])">
</p>
```

"terms" and "conditions" properties changing depending to the language so i can manage sentence sequence to defined language with any html tag

> in component

$t("message", [$t("paramater_1"),$t("parameter_2")])

> in json file

"message" : "some text {0} some text with html {1}....."